# ajax call to mapped URL

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I am trying to make an AJAX call to a localhost URL that I am hosting via java. The URL currently only holds a String.

But when I try to call it from my javascript, I don't get any return value. The code/URL doesn't even work.

Javascript code(For website):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onload = function() {
if(true){
    alert('hello!');
    document.getElementById('newgame').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;

}
};

xhr.open('GET', 'localhost:8080/highscore', true);
xhr.send(null);`
```

JAVA class code(currently running):

```
@RestController
public class Server {



    @RequestMapping("/highscore")
    public String highScore() {

        return "test";


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't using jQuery instead, as below

```
<html>

<head>
<script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
req_url = "http://localhost:8080/highscore";
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:req_url,
        success:function(data){
            alert('hello!');
            document.getElementById('newgame').innerHTML = data;
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but it returns all the content in the class, literally all the text, not just the String. Any idea as to why?

Answer (score 0):

Replace localhost:8080/highscore by http://localhost:8080/highscore